# How to determine the summing range of the $j_{12}$ for $ 6j$ symbols?

Tags: angular-momentum, representation-theory

$$
        |j_{1},j_{2}j_{3}(j_{23});j\rangle = \sum_{j_{12}}(-1)^{j_{1}+j_{2}+j_{3}+j}\hat{j}_{12}\hat{j}_{23}
        \begin{Bmatrix}
            j_{1}&j_{2}&j_{12}\\
            j_{3}&j&j_{23}
        \end{Bmatrix}
        |j_{1}j_{2}(j_{12})j_{3};j\rangle
$$
where, $\hat{j}=\sqrt{2j+1}$.

I want to design Mathematica codes for this formula. However, I do not where are the summing range of the $j_{12}$. But for a special case, for example, three spin-$\frac{1}{2}$, if they couple into total angular momentum $j=1/2$, we have the expression as follows.

$$
    |\frac{1}{2},(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})0;\frac{1}{2}\rangle = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}){\color{red}0},\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}){\color{red}1},\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\rangle
$$
Yes, calculating by hand, I can easy know that the values of $j_{12}$ I have to take. But for generalized vaules of $j_{1},j_{2},j_{3}$, how can I determine the range of the $j_{12}$ when I design *Mathematica* codes for this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By construction $j_{12}$ is the result of coupling $j_1$ and $j_2$ so the possible values of $j_{12}$ range from $\vert j_1-j_2\vert$ to $j_1+j_2$, incrementing in steps of 1.

In your specific case $j_1=j_2=1/2$ so the range of $j_{12}$ is between $0$ and $1$ in steps of $1$, *i.e.* precisely $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Following your analysis, I designed the *Mathematica* codes for this formula and checked it is true with this summing range. Thanking.